# java lib connect to another lib error

Tags: java, jar, lib

I've created my own jar file which includes javamail-1.4.5 lib. and when I run a batch file that starts the main class I got this error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Store
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Store
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm using the following query in batch file

```
java -cp ../libs/myLib.jar main.Main
```

The strange thing is that if I run my main class via eclipse I haven't errors. 
Can someone help me about why is this happening and what I have to do to solve it?

Fix: java -cp ../libs/mail.jar;../libs/myLib.jar main.Main

Comment: You have not given reference of library in classpath. This is not strange, it is obvious. In eclipse, lib must be in classpath

Comment: @Ravi in eclipse, lib is in the classpath...
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/mail.jar"/>

Comment: @SapLalo how did you created your jar ? using eclipse or command line ?

Comment: @Ravi via eclipse

Comment: @SapLalo _"in eclipse, lib is in the classpath"_ which is why it works in Eclipse.  You must specify that library (and all other libraries you use) on the command line as well.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for hints, How I can do that? (Sorry for this kind of question but I'm new on these things)

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks! I fount it!
java -cp ../libs/mail.jar;../libs/myLib.jar main.Main